# ajax fallback when no internet connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, local-storage

The following code submits data to the server. The data is actually stored in the localStorage before submit to server. This is due to my requirement for the user to be able to use my system without an internet connection.

The problem is that when there is no internet connection, obviously it cant post the data to the server. What should I do in this situation?

```
$('#btnSync').on('click', function(e) {
    var my_data = {};
    var my_value = [];

    for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
        if((localStorage.key( i ).includes('set'))){
            var lsItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) ));

            allItems[localStorage.key( i )] = lsItems;
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "action.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'action':'btnSync','allItems':allItems},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $.notify(
                {
                    message: data.message
                },
                {
                    type: data.status,
                    placement: {
                        from: "top",
                        align: "left"
                    },
                    newest_on_top: true,
                    delay: 0
                }
            );
        },
        error: function(data){
            $.notify(
                {
                    message: 'Unexpected error occured, please kindly contact System Administrator'
                },
                {
                    type: 'danger',
                    placement: {
                        from: "top",
                        align: "left"
                    },
                    newest_on_top: true,
                    delay: 0
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your error callback will be called. Why not maintain a seperate queue for data that failed to push to the server (in local storage). Periodically check if you are online and replay the ajax calls.

Comment: have a look at `window.addEventListener('online',  sendToServer)
window.addEventListener('offline', alertUser)`

Comment: @mode777 I keep the data in localStorage to avoid data missing upon ajax submission failed. So that at least I have a copy of the data in the localStorage. Periodical check mean using javascript setInterval? Seems like you have experience, can you elaborate more or with a sample maybe?

Comment: @4LeaveCover: Unfortunately I don't have much ecperience with such system. However using the `online` event as @Gildas, Tambo suggested seems like a better choice. Just make sure your target browser [supports it ](http://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status). If you serialize your ajax calls to local storage (e.g. url, payload, method) you can resend the data once the `online` event is fired

Comment: Hmm.. I guess the objective is simple. Instead of checking for online or offline as @Gildas.Tambo mentioned (because different browser have different definition of online/offline), I just run the ajax using setInterval should be better. Because whenever ajax connected to my server, the data will be recorded in the database, else the data just remain in localStorage until the next interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check whether connection/server is up using a similar ajax call. Look for

```
statusCode.status == 0
```

in error and give destination unreachable/Internet down notice to user. You can create this ajax call as a promise in a function and use that before all your ajax calls, and ask user to connect to the Internet then retry.

Comment: Where should I put this line of code? Is it in `error: function(data){if(statusCode.status==0){//notify user}}`?

Comment: yes, in error, or in newer code style in fail like:
$.post('balbal.html', {}, function(data) {
    // ... my code ...
})
.fail(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});